# Can a rotating body see it's own reflection?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, rotation

So my question is this: Say I'm able to get close to, but not achieve the speed of light. I want to look at the back of my head in the mirror, would it be possible to turn around before the light from the back of my head stopped reflecting off the mirror; can I turn around without breaking light speed and look at the back of my head in a mirror?

Answer (score 3):

If the mirror is far enough, you don't even need to move that fast. If it takes you one second to turn your head around and the mirror is $c$ meters away, you'll have another full second before the light comes back to you. There's nothing that relativistic about this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to move very fast at all if the mirror is very far away and you have a very good telescope...

But for a reasonable set up, you would have to be rotating quickly. In order to actually focus and see yourself, you would have to stop too.